# Evenly distribute rectangles

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I am looking for an algorithm to evenly distribute a given number of same-sized rectangles in another larger rectangle.

For example if there is only one child rectangle, it should be placed in the exact center of the parent.

If there are two rectangles and the parent is wider and than it is high, then the children should be placed next to each other.

If there would be three child rectangles two of them should be placed next to each other and the last one in the center below them.

Please share any links to algorithms about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete algorithm for you. But it seems reasonable to start with a recursive subdivision of space. Get familiar with quadtrees and you might come up with an idea how to use it for this problem.